# Necesito que la funcion me lea todos los datos registrados en el vecto,

Tags: c, bucle-for

El vector nombre lee nombres pero cuando pido buscar uno ingresado en otra función únicamente pasa el primero o no se qué tengo mal en el `for`, pero necesito que lea cualquier dato del vector, no solo el primero.

---

```
void CONSULTAXC (float totalPag[100], int cantidad[100], 
char nombre[100][30], char TipoPastel[100][30])

{

    char busq[100][30], opc = { 'n' };
    int i=0;
    system("cls");
    do
    {
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del juguete que desea buscar: ");
        gets_s(busq[i]);
        gets_s(busq[i]);
        for (i = 0; strcmp(nombre[i], busq[i]) == 0; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(nombre[i], busq[i]) == 0)
            {
                printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombre[i]);
                printf("Tipo de Pastel: %s\n", TipoPastel[i]);
                printf("Cantidad: %d\n\n", cantidad[i]);
                printf("Total a Pagar: %.2f pesos\n", totalPag[i]);
                Sleep(2000);
            }
            else {
                printf("No se encontro algun cliente con esa info..\n");
            }     
        }
        printf("Desea buscar a otro Cliente?:. [Si(s)/No(n)]\n");
        scanf_s("%c", &opc);
        system("cls");
    } while (opc != 'n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; strcmp(nombre[i], busq[i]) == 0; i++)
```

La condición para que repita el bucle es que `nombre[i] == busq[i]`. En el momento en el que esa igualdad no se cumpla, se abandonará el bucle.

Si necesitas iterar por todos los elementos tienes que forzar el bucle para que itere toda la colección y mover la condición **dentro** del bucle:

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
  if( strcmp(nombre[i], busq[i]) == 0 )
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Adicinalmente:

- El `else` no debería encontrarse dentro del `for` ya que con esa medida solo conseguirás que el mensaje te salga varias veces (una por cada registro que no coincida).
- Únicamente estás realizando una búsqueda (y no 30), así que `busq` no debería ser un array de cadenas de caracteres.
- Tampoco es recomendable que uses literales en el código... complica el mantenimiento del mismo.
- Fíjate que estás pidiendo dos veces seguidas el nombre a buscar:

  ```
  printf("Ingrese el nombre del juguete que desea buscar: ");
  gets_s(busq[i]);
  gets_s(busq[i]);
  ```

Conjugando todo esto una posible solución sería:

```
#define NUM_ELEMENTOS 100
#define MAX_LENGTH 30

void CONSULTAXC (float totalPag[NUM_ELEMENTOS],
                 int cantidad[NUM_ELEMENTOS],
                 char nombre[NUM_ELEMENTOS][MAX_LENGTH],
                 char TipoPastel[NUM_ELEMENTOS][MAX_LENGTH])
{
  char busq[MAX_LENGTH], opc = { 'n' };
  system("cls");
  do
  {
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del juguete que desea buscar: ");
    gets_s(busq);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_ELEMENTOS; i++)
    {
      if (strcmp(nombre[i], busq[i]) == 0)
        break;
    }

    if( i < NUM_ELEMENTOS )
    {
      printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombre[i]);
      printf("Tipo de Pastel: %s\n", TipoPastel[i]);
      printf("Cantidad: %d\n\n", cantidad[i]);
      printf("Total a Pagar: %.2f pesos\n", totalPag[i]);
      Sleep(2000);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("No se encontro algun cliente con esa info..\n");
    }     

    printf("Desea buscar a otro Cliente?:. [Si(s)/No(n)]\n");
    scanf_s("%c", &opc);
    system("cls");
  } while (opc != 'n');
}
```